# Exporting IMU sensor ( accelerometer , gyroscope) readings into a data file along with their timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using a IMU sensor and fetching 3 readings (XYZ_acceleration , XYZ_angular velocity , XYZ_magnetometer) I want to export them in single data file along with their timestamp. I managed to export to 3 separate data file without timestamp.

```py
from altimu10v5.lsm6ds33 import LSM6DS33
from altimu10v5.lis3mdl import LIS3MDL
from altimu10v5.lps25h import LPS25H
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import csv
import calendar
import time

lsm6ds33 = LSM6DS33()
lsm6ds33.enable()

lis3mdl = LIS3MDL()
lis3mdl.enable()

lps25h = LPS25H
lis3mdl.enable()

ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())


while True:


    accel_raw=lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_raw()
    accel_gforce=lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()
    accel_angle=lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_angles()
    gyro_raw=lsm6ds33.get_gyroscope_raw()
    gyro_ang_vel=lsm6ds33.get_gyro_angular_velocity()
    magnet=lis3mdl.get_magnetometer_raw()


    aaa1=open('data_accele_f_force.dat','ab')
    np.savetxt(aaa1 ,np.expand_dims(accel_gforce, axis=0),  fmt='%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f') 

    aaa2=open('data_accele_raw.dat','ab')
    np.savetxt(aaa2 ,np.expand_dims(accel_raw, axis=0),  fmt='%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f') 

    aaa3=open('data_accele_angles.dat','ab')
    np.savetxt(aaa3 ,np.expand_dims(accel_angle, axis=0), fmt='%4.2f %4.2f') 

sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using dummy values for the sensor readings, but this below should work:

```py
import calendar
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import time

while True:
    # get time
    timestamp = ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
    # sensor readings
    timestamped_sensor_readings = np.ndarray((0,), np.float32)
    # get sensor placeholder values
    timestamped_sensor_readings = np.append(timestamped_sensor_readings, np.random.rand(3))
    timestamped_sensor_readings = np.append(timestamped_sensor_readings, np.random.rand(3))
    timestamped_sensor_readings = np.append(timestamped_sensor_readings, np.random.rand(2))

    # write format for readings
    write_fmt = " ".join("%4.2f" for _ in timestamped_sensor_readings)
    # append time
    timestamped_sensor_readings = np.append(timestamped_sensor_readings, float(timestamp))
    write_fmt += " %.0f"

    with open("mydatafile.txt", "ab") as f:
        np.savetxt(f, np.expand_dims(timestamped_sensor_readings, axis=0),  fmt=write_fmt)

    sleep(1)
```

Output is filled in as below:

```sh
$ tail -f mydatafile.txt 
0.72 0.90 0.77 0.37 0.51 0.46 0.41 0.76 1560186762
0.69 0.49 0.62 0.32 0.60 0.61 0.59 0.52 1560186763
0.17 0.42 0.97 0.07 0.83 0.67 0.48 0.43 1560186764
0.10 0.02 0.07 0.16 0.05 0.83 0.51 0.31 1560186765
0.64 0.78 0.29 0.96 0.04 0.19 0.11 0.43 1560186766
0.12 0.87 0.04 0.99 0.57 0.81 0.05 0.57 1560186767
```